# vlookup increment by a fixed number

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to use vlookup function but i need to increment by a fixed number.

Here is my current formula at cell D22.

=VLOOKUP($B$22,$B$6:$XX$17,COLUMN()-2,FALSE)

For D23, I need to have the following formula

=VLOOKUP($B$22,$B$6:$XX$17,COLUMN()+1,FALSE)

And so forth so I want to increase the index by 3 for each cell below.

Is there a faster way to do it?

Here is a sample, same idea but increment by 2.

[image]

Comment: I don't know if it'll work, so I'll comment for now, but does `=VLOOKUP($B$22,$B$6:$XX$17,COLUMN()-(IF(ROW()=22,-2,E21+5)),FALSE)` in D22 work, when you drag down?  Basically, I replaced `Column()-2` with `Column()-IF(ROW()=22,-2,E21+5)`

Comment: thanks for the input but it doesn't work the way i want, it gives the wrong value for D22 then its invalid values for the rest.

Comment: Can you post some sample data, or how it's laid out so we can try on our side?

Comment: the yellow part is the pivot table and below is where i m doing the lookups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For D22, use your current condition [ COLUMN()-2 ] with the following appended:

+(ROW()-22)*3  [ so it would be:  COLUMN()-2+(ROW()-22)*3  ]

Then copying down the result of ROW() is incremented by 1 each row, then muliplied by 3 for the increment of +3 each row.

Comment: thanks, i get the idea now. I can apply to other lookups that requires to increment by a fixed number.

Comment: Oh man I was so close when I was messing around with it. I was so focused on adding columns I simply forgot to multiply. Well done!